# Hibernate and OSGi integration, it unable to load hibernate configuration file

Tags: hibernate, osgi

I'm creating OSGi dynamic bundle which should communicate with database and I am using Hibernate as I used it in non OSGI application.
I putted original hibernate jars in the OSGi project's lib dir, and make sure those jars are on the project's build path and runtime class-path, I copied all configuration files(i. e. hibernate-cfg.xml) in the root of the OSGi bundled jar.
When I execute my bundle (JAR) inside OSGi container it throws error for not finding hibernate-cfg.xml file.

Maybe somebody knows good example how to do that?

At the moment I'm getting following  error

2013-10-14 14:56:10 ERROR HibernateUtil:41 - SessionFactory creation failed:org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found

Thank you in advance

Comment: you most likely need to use the latest version available from Hibernate, cause older versions do have some issues with classloaders and loading resource files.

Comment: My issue is resolved, I just update hibernate jar version with 3.2.6.ga and it start working.
Thanks Achim Nierbeck for your response and clue.

Answer (score 0):

Please folows step:

1. Download Hibernate zip file at hibernate.org (Now Hibernate4.3.0Final), 
     but i test Ok with Hibernate 4.2.8Final
2. Create Project A as osgi project: 
       (Project A will contain Hibernate osgi loader, 
         and  hibernate Library, have no your Entities class,
         and have no hibernate.cfg.xml)
        Extract hibernate-release-4.2.8.Final.zip
        to directory, copy package source (org....) in 
         \hibernate-release-4.2.8.Final\project\hibernate-osgi\src\main\java
        into src of Project A.

   ```
    Setup Activator class:  (MANIFEST.MF)
     Bundle-Activator: org.hibernate.osgi.HibernateBundleActivator

    Create directory 'libs/hiber-4.2.8' in project A:
    Copy All <DIR>\hibernate-release-4.2.8.Final\lib to your 'libs/hiber-4.2.8',
   ```

Set Bundle Classpath: (MANIFEST.MF)

```
    Bundle-ClassPath: .,
     libs/hiber-4.2.8/jpa/hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.8.Final.jar,
     libs/hiber-4.2.8/optional/ehcache/ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar,
     libs/hiber-4.2.8/optional/ehcache/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar,
     libs/hiber-4.2.8/required/antlr-2.7.7.jar,
     libs/hiber-4.2.8/required/dom4j-1.6.1.jar,
     libs/hiber-4.2.8/required/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar,
     libs/hiber-4.2.8/required/hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar,
     libs/hiber-4.2.8/required/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar,
     libs/hiber-4.2.8/required/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar,
     libs/hiber-4.2.8/required/jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar,
     libs/hiber-4.2.8/required/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
```

Set Export packages:

```
Export-Package: javax.persistence,
org.hibernate,
org.hibernate.annotations,
org.hibernate.cfg,
org.hibernate.criterion,
org.hibernate.dialect,
org.hibernate.dialect.function,
org.hibernate.exception,
org.hibernate.internal.util,
org.hibernate.jdbc,
org.hibernate.mapping,
org.hibernate.osgi,
org.hibernate.property,
org.hibernate.service,
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl,
org.hibernate.type
```

==> Now ready Project A (Osgi project).

3. Create Osgi Project B, in Project B with have your Entity class, 
        file hibernate.cfg.xml , Library for Jdbc driver you can declare in B osgi.

   In B Activator:

   ```
   public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
       Activator.context = bundleContext;
       this.loadOsgiHibernateService(bundleContext);
   }

   private void loadOsgiHibernateService(BundleContext bundleContext) {

       ServiceReference<?> ref = context
               .getServiceReference(SessionFactory.class.getName());
       if (ref != null) {
           SessionFactory factory = (SessionFactory) context.getService(ref);
                   // Ready session factory. 
                   Session session= factory.getCurrentSession();
               }
   }
   ```