# Creating Hibernate Session in OSGi Service with getServiceReference

Tags: hibernate, session, osgi, sessionfactory

**---update 2---**

Seems like the weird bug was caused by another weird bug concerning the bundle start order. Even though I had set the start Order to "project A, THEN project B", it would sometimes start it the other way around, thereby causing the problem with the ServiceReference. Seems to finally work now without any problems.

Thank you again for taking your time!

**---update---**

After testing my program again this morning, the problem was suddenly gone. I had not even modified the code at that point. After that I got pretty far with my service, but while I was trying to solve a problem with loading the mapping class, the problem suddenly reappeared. 
Restarting Eclipse did nothing, restarting my PC solved the problem again. *It seems to have no connection to my code whatsoever...*

A few minutes ago I got my service to work, I did a few test entries in my database, everything fine. Now I'm working on fleshing out my service (providing more options to interact with the database etc.) and the problem is there *again*, even though I didn't change anything about that part of the code.

**TL;DR:**

Seems to be a completely random bug.

Thank you for your replies so far, anyway. I'll consider those options if I ever need to dig deeper into the matter, but right now I think I'm contend with having proven that my program works, because this sporadic bug doesn't seem to be my fault. (It was just an excercise anyway, the program has no actual practical use for me).

**---original---**
So I've been working on a simple OSGi Service that uses Hibernate to access a database.

---optional wall of text---

Most of the information on this topic seems to be fairly outdated, mainly because the official OSGi-support for hibernate is barely a year old. Everything before that is rather complicated and not very helpful. (I spend quite some time on that before giving up).
The devguide on this topic (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch17.html) is also rather sparse (I'm a beginner to both Hibernate and OSGi and this guide seems to expect a fairly in-depth knowledge). I tried getting the quickstart project "unmanaged native" to work, but I haven't used maven or karaf before, and ran into some problems there.

After that I just tried to integrate their HibernateUtil (https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4.2/documentation/src/main/docbook/quickstart/tutorials/osgi/unmanaged-native/src/main/java/org/hibernate/osgitest/HibernateUtil.java) into my own program, but I would always get a nullPointerException at this line: `sf = (SessionFactory) context.getService( sr );` because `sr` is `null`. (sr gets specified in the line above, `ServiceReference sr = context.getServiceReference( SessionFactory.class.getName() );` )

---end of text---

So basicly I stumbled across this **step by step guide** in an answer: [Hibernate and OSGi integration, it unable to load hibernate configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357487/hibernate-and-osgi-integration-it-unable-to-load-hibernate-configuration-file) and it seemed to work well for me so far (far less work with dependencies and required bundles), but then I got to the line `ServiceReference<?> ref = context.getServiceReference(SessionFactory.class.getName());`
and I already knew what was going to happen; yup, `ref` is `null`, therefore it won't create a session.

After finding a few other examples of "working" Hibernate Services, all of them seem to create their Session in a similar fashion, but I can't find anyone else having this problem.

**What am I doing wrong, what could be causing this problem?** Is there something else missing?

note: for simplicity reasons, assume that my program looks exactly like in the above mentioned answer. The only additional step I have done was to put the "Project A" package into the required Bundes for "B", then I start the bundles in eclipse equinox.

No Errors, but in debugging I can tell that `ref` is `null`

(Obviously I intend to fancy it out a bit, but for that i need to get it to work in the first place...)

Answer (score 0):

First about your specific question. I am not sure you can directly get the SessionFactory.

What does work is to create a bundle with a persistence unit that is marked with a special Manifest header (see in tutorial). If you then have aries jpa and hibernate installed then you will get a EntityManagerFactory as a service. So best start is to work with this and use jpa instead of the specific hibernate API.

If you need the hibernate Session then you can use the unwrap method of EntityManager to get access to it.

Much better though than using the EntityManagerFactory directly is to use the blueprint extensions from aries jpa which provide container managed mode. So you can work with the EntityManager like in Java EE and do not have to open and close it.

I am currently creating a new example to show how to work with hibernate in karaf. Unfortunately it will take some more time.

For now take a look at my [Apache karaf DB tutorial](http://liquid-reality.de/pages/viewinfo.action?pageId=6586413)

It shows how to work with DataSources and how to do JPA with openjpa. The example only needs to be modified slightly to work with hibernate.

I also got the start of an [hibernate example](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/db/hibernate). It is probably not fully working at the moment. It might give you the right clues how to go on though. If you have any questions you can also reach me via mail (address is on my website).

Comment: I now finished my example for hibernate. You can find it here:
https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/tasklist-cdi

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to your question directly, but if you just want to get Hibernate working with OSGi, you might want to take a look here: [Amdatu JPA](http://amdatu.org/components/jpa.html).

Amdatu JPA makes it easy to work with JPA (either OpenJPA, EclipseLink or Hibernate) in OSGi, including declarative transaction management.